# Unable to find suitable method for property URL? ComboPooledDataSource, Spring Boot DataSourceBuilder 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am upgrading to spring boot 2.7.0 from 2.3.12.RELEASE as that has vulnerabilities.
My application uses c3p0 for connection pooling and I need to keep using that.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.jdbc.UnsupportedDataSourcePropertyException: Unable to find suitable method for url
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.UnsupportedDataSourcePropertyException.throwIf(UnsupportedDataSourcePropertyException.java:36) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$ReflectionDataSourceProperties.getMethod(DataSourceBuilder.java:560) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$ReflectionDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:542) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.informatica.cloud.service.admin.config.PersistenceConfig.dataSource(PersistenceConfig.java:21) ~[main/:?]
    at com.informatica.cloud.service.admin.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bae0fe3.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at com.informatica.cloud.service.admin.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bae0fe3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ab5ae17.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.informatica.cloud.service.admin.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bae0fe3.dataSource(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
```

**Property:**
`spring.datasource.type=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`

The thing that breaks this is the change in DataSourceBuilder in spring boot 2.5.x or higher.

**DataSourceBuilder:**

```
private enum DataSourceProperty {

        URL(false, "url", "URL"),
```

DataSourceBuilder will look for setUrl or setURL in the ComboPooledDataSource class and that class has setJdbcUrl method, hence the exception.

**Any suggestions to not create dataSource bean manually and use auto configuration without breaking the code?**

**Edit:
application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db-url:3307/service
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.datasource.type=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
spring.datasource.pool.driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: `spring.datasource.url` you need to pass the url against this property in your application property

Comment: Yes, that I'm passing that's why this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed what our documentation states but we used to support C3P0 before. I've created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31920 to restore the support.

Answer (score 0):

As per spring boot documentation they support only below database pooling

- HikariCP
- Tomcat pooling Datasource
- Commons DBCP2
- Oracle UCP & OracleDataSource
- Spring Framework’s SimpleDriverDataSource
- H2 JdbcDataSource
- PostgreSQL PGSimpleDataSource

So you need to define the `Datasource` manually for `C3P0`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource.connection-pool

***Update:***

Thanks [Stephane Nicoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613628/stephane-nicoll) for taking this up and doing the changes in the code to enable the support for CP30.

**Reference:** https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31920

Comment: Thanks for the response. My goal is to achieve what was already working fine in Spring boot 2.3.x. Custom configuration I am able to do but that'll be tedious for all my other microservices. Hence looking for a generic solution that can solve this issue.